# Add Value to next empty row below specified headers - then clear value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a Google Apps Script that allows me to:

1. Search Item
2. Select Item from Returned Results (=ImportHTML)
3. Add item to next empty row in (A11-A11+)
4. Clear Term in A3

Is this something that is possible in Google Apps Scripts?

**Example**
[image]

```
function button1() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Returns the first cell 
  var cell = sheet.getRange("D3"); sheet.appendRow([cell]) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the last row of the sheet, and use that value in the range.  The `getRange()` method has 4 variations.  (Just so you know.)

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);
var rangeAtAppendLocation = sh
   .getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, column to begin at, rows to write, columns);

rangeAtAppendLocation.setValues(Two dimensional array);
```

You can append values with the `appendRow(one D Arry)` method.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name).appendRow([array]);
```

You can clear a cell with:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name).getRange(3, 3).clearContent();
```

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name).appendRow([array]);` The problem with this is that I would be choosing one item to append ... (By Selecting it's corresponding Checkmark) I think this is to append the entire result... (D3:D7)

Comment: is this something that would work ? (obv I would need to make a function for each button) 
  `function button1() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
     // Returns the first cell
     var cell = sheet.getRange("D3");

     sheet.appendRow([cell])
     }`

Comment: That will put the single value after the last row of data in column A.  `appendRow()` will always start in column A.  So if you want D3 to go into column D, `appendRow()` won't work.